# How can i expand a list if no child list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How can I set the parent list to expanded by default `data-expanded="true" if the child list is empty or if there is no sub list?

```
<ul class="treeview">
    <li data-expanded="false" class="panel-handler rparty" data-id="@item.ID">
        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>@item.PartyName
        <ul>
            @foreach (var sp in rp.Details)
            {
             <li class="panel-handler sParty" data-expanded="false" data-id="@sp.SpartyID"></li>            
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I tried this but this expands everything. I am looking to expand if there is no child List otherwise collapses.

```
$('li.rparty').not(':has(li.sParty').attr('data-expanded', true);
```

Comment: Class names are spelled differently in the html than in the selector you use

Comment: @charlietfl sorry that was a mistake, fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the HTML this is to work with in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see the problem in action and be able to help.